# Why do I have to kill gpg-agent to sign my commits?

Tags: git, gnupg

[GitHub recently announced verified commits](https://github.com/blog/2144-gpg-signature-verification), so I took this opportunity to implement GPG and start using keys. When I want to start committing, I get the following:

```
$ git commit

You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "John Doe <johndoe@email.com>"
4096-bit RSA key, ID ABCD1234, created 2016-04-08

gpg: problem with the agent - disabling agent use
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I went online and searched for a solution, and one site (for a mail provider) suggested to `killall gpg-agent`, and it worked. Now, I can sign commits by entering my passphrase.

Is `gpg-agent` necessary? It seems to come with GPG when I installed it, but if I have to kill it to sign my commits, it would seem that I there is something that I am not understanding. How can I fix this so that I can have `gpg-agent`running and be able to sign my commits?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I just figured out how to use `gpg-agent` on my Mac today.  I was blocked after hitting the same error as you:

```
gpg: problem with the agent - disabling agent use
```

## tldr; How I fixed it

For my setup, I was able to fix this by installing `pinentry-mac` and pointing `gpg-agent` to use it, thus popping up a GUI prompt as required.

```
1. install pinentry-mac
% brew install pinentry-mac
2. update gpg-agent conf
# manually change ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf's pinentry-program to /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
3. update shell's view of PATH contents
% hash -r
4. restart gpg-agent
# however you normally do it (see below for how I run it manually)
```

## Details on debugging

I debugged this by restarting the `gpg-agent` manually.  I first commented out the configs in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, then I ran this command to restart the gpg-agent with `--verbose`:

```
% killall gpg-agent && \
  eval $(gpg-agent --pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry --default-cache-ttl 60 --daemon --verbose)
```

Then I ran a test command and saw the error we've both listed above, as well as a new one:

```
# update the MY_GPG_KEY_ID as appropriate
% echo hi | gpg -e -r $(MY_GPG_KEY_ID) | gpg -d --use-agent
...
gpg-agent[60604]: command get_passphrase failed: Device not configured
gpg: problem with the agent - disabling agent use
...
```

I eventually realized (after reading [this article](http://harryrschwartz.com/2014/11/05/configuring-gpg-agent-on-a-mac.html) and [this GPG page](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Common-Problems.html)) that `GPG_TTY` was *not* set by the steps I was following for starting up `gpg-agent`.  So once I set that variable everything "worked":

```
% killall gpg-agent && \
  eval $(gpg-agent --pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry --default-cache-ttl 60 --daemon --verbose)
% export GPG_TTY=`tty`
# Now the below command succeeds
% echo hi | gpg -e -r $(MY_GPG_KEY_ID) | gpg -d --use-agent
```

In the midst of this exercise I was trying a lot of different options, and discovered that the `pinentry-mac` GUI prompter "just worked".

## Avoiding GUI passphrase prompter

If you don't want a GUI prompter popping up, then I think it would be sufficient to ensure that the following env variables are being set in every terminal:

- `GPG_TTY`

  - e.g., you can put this line into your .bashrc:
  - `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`
- `GPG_AGENT_INFO`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use Ubuntu. :sweat_smile: Let me see if I can apply your research to my problem.

Comment: The solution to my problem apparently was simpler. According to [this manual](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html), I have to specify to GPG which TTY I am using, once that was done, everything worked great.

If you modify your answer to reflect this, I can accept your answer.

Comment: @cj-duncan I put the detail about setting `GPT_TTY` in your `.bashrc`  (I have no idea how to "@" you with the space in your username :) )

Comment: Worked great for me on my Mac, I was just about to resort to entering my password a bajillion times to do a release.  Thanks!

Comment: @funkybro: glad it helped you!